# double delay code for single variable two condition

Tags: c#

in my project, i need to code for X1 in such a way as 
in local variables i declare and wrote the condition as

```
x1 = 0;

if(in1_w == 1)
{
   x1 = 1;
}
if((in1_w == 1) && (in2_w == 1))
{
   x1 = 2;
}
```

i's an microcontroller based in and out so, now i need to know how to right the delay code `if x1=1 and x1=2`. i have written as

```
for(k=0;k<=x1;k++)
{
    delay_40sec();
}
```

but don't know how to write separately?
waiting for your kind help plz

Comment: how can x1 be equal to 1 and 2 at the same time?

Comment: What relevance to the question does the first chunk of code have?

Comment: No need to test twice for `in1_w`: `x1 = (in1_w == 1) ? (in2_w == 1) ? 2 : 1 : 0;`

Comment: Seems like something that may be better done using bitwise operations, especially if it is being used in microcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)
```

where x is in milliseconds.

However be aware that it is not guaranteed to be accurate nor repeatable.